# Android : Toolbar visible in layout but cant see in emulator?

Tags: android, layout

[Here is the image of what i need to create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQURD.png)I want to make a transparent toolbar in my Android application. I have placed a toolbar in my XML code and it is seeing in the design window. When i run the program the toolbar is not visible in the emulator.

Here is my XML code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.jithin.image_custom.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/album1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="435dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/cheese_1"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:minHeight="100dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Checkout this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) for further customisations & doubts

Comment: I want  to make image visible inside the toolbar. That is i am making my toolbar transparent here . so i want my toolbar on the image view

Comment: then you have to use imageView inside toolbar tag, can i know why you need the toolbar, so that i can edit the answer properly

Comment: I have uploaded an image in my post. I want to place a transparent toolbar as in the image

Comment: did you want like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FLxPPl.jpg), if not can you show a sample ui

Comment: Now the toombar is visible on the emulator. can u give the code for getting button on toolbar as shown in image

Answer (score 0):

Please Do

```
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

In your sytle It may work ... Like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```